# VSCODE .env pythpath dynamicly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I know that if I create a .env file in my workspacefolder and add follwing:

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/my/root/folder
```

that this gets taken as my root folder which is very nice.

But after a lot of research I couldn't find a solution to set this dynamicly:

```
PYTHONPATH=${workspaceFolder}
```

doesn't work. This var is just empty.

Is there a way to add the workspaceFolder path dynamically?